# Nesting Linear Layouts with Weights, Why Considered Bad?

Tags: android, xml, performance, layout

So, I've been developing on Android since about Feb 2011. One thing I've always been acutely aware of is that Nesting Linear Layouts with weight and weight sums is 'bad for performance' and the compiler (well at least eclipse did) thew a warning fit when ever you dd so.

However, it's been my experience that doing this has no noticeable impact on the user experience, or speed when switching screens. As an experiment I created the following screen which deliberately features nothing other than a mega O.T.T. use of weights and nested linear layouts. I've used contrasting colors to show all the linear layouts used. The benefits is that it looks the same on large and small screens.

[image: Mega Nested Linear Layout with Weights]

I've tried it on a Galaxy S4, Galaxy Note 10.0, Galaxy note 3 7", and very small low powered Galaxy Neo. I've tried it on Gingerbread, Cream Sandwich, Kitkat and Lollupop and do not see any perceptible speed difference between this screen an a simple one with 4 buttons on a relative layout.

So what makes this such a bad idea? What is going on under the hood that makes this a less than idea solution? Will all this change the moment I add drawables or images into the mix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what makes this such a bad idea?

It's not a bad idea. It is not free, either.

In particular, your scenario is fairly simple, despite your protestations to the contrary. While your layout is rather complex, it is rendered once. Hence, while you may drop a few frames while rendering it, that price is paid one time (or, more accurately, one time per activity/fragment that is using this layout).

Where per-layout expense becomes a much bigger problem is when it is magnified by having several of them that get animated around, such as rows in a `ListView`/`RecyclerView`, or pages in a `ViewPager`. Now, we are going through *lots and lots* of rendering passes, as the user swipes and causes us to redraw our content. Each individual row in the list might be significantly simpler than your layout, but we're also going to be trying to draw those many times per second. And, while a couple of dropped frames may not be noticeable in your case, dropped frames during animation is pretty much the definition of "jank" for an Android UI.

So long as you have no jank -- IOW, you are not dropping any frames, as reported by `Choreographer` in LogCat or as seen in the `gfxinfo` overlay through Developer Options -- then your layout is fine, at least as far as I and probably most users are concerned. Conversely, if you *are* dropping frames, trying to figure out more efficient layouts, perhaps even custom `ViewGroups` rather than general-purpose ones, may help alleviate that jank.

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here has to do with how [Android positions your views on screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=we6poP0kw6E&index=39&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE). Any time that a position changes with respect to a view, then a "layout" pass cascade through the view hierarchy, touching each view and performing some calculations (similar for changing "sizes" kicks off a "measure" pass).

Some layout containers, like RelativeLayout, have to force a 2nd "layout" pass to kick off; Once all the views have calculated their desired position, ReltativeLayout needs to then re-position everything again based on it's layout properties.

This causes a [Double Layout Taxation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dB3_vgS-Uqo&index=8&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE) trough the view hierarchy; which isn't free.

Now, if you have a *shallow* hierarchy, the overhead of this action is insignificant. Where this starts to run into a problem is when you've got a deep hierarchy, with multiple double-layout containers in it. For example, having a RelativeLayout at the root, which contains LinearLayouts that have "measure with largest child" set on it. The result is that the leaf-node views will have "layout" called on them ~8x times.

The performance impact of this is directly correlated to how complex your layout/measure passes are in your scene. If nothing is problematic, maybe a 12x-per-view layout pass isn't a big deal on high-end devices. However if one of the leaf nodes has a complex layout pass, well, then you're just wasting cycles.

The main topic here is to profile for things that are a problem, but keep in mind that setting things up the wrong way is just wasting performance that could be used elsewhere.

Comment: Wow Colt, what an honor.  Looks like I've got some reading to do.